# Bad practice to do "interesting" work inside a Stream.peek()?

Tags: java, java-stream

Scenario: I have a collection of objects that I want to do some work to, transform them, and collect the results. Initially, I had two map calls:

```
objects.stream()
       .map(o -> {
                // do something interesting...
                // set some fields...
                return o;
            })
       .map(transformer::mapToSomethingElse)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My IDE recommended using `.peek` for the first map, since I'm just returning the same input. When I read the API notes for peek, I see the following:

> This method exists mainly to support debugging

Is my usage of peek a bad idea? The operations happening within peek are necessary, so if they were optimized away, that would be bad. Due to the way this stream operation is structured, I don't have any reason to believe the peek would be elided.

Of course I could just write this with a for loop, but I like the syntax of streams so I use them wherever I can.

Comment: The "bad practice" you're truly running into (and not warned about) is introducing side-effects into your stream. This isn't as bad on a sequential stream, but when made parallel can become a nightmare. It's also generally against most functional programming paradigms. That said, if it works, it works, as long as you understand the implications. `#peek` would work fine if you're just returning the same reference, but `#map` may also be more self-documenting that you are mutating the stream.

Comment: Using `map` is already bad practice, because you shouldn't modify the elements of the stream as you consume it. Side-effects should be avoided. If you want to modify the elements of a collection, use a loop.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the use case for streams in general.  Why not use a loop in all cases?  I think the answer is some problems work well (are cleanly implemented) using the stream syntax.  However, some is not all.  Don't force a stream implementation unless it's a clear good fit, imo.  (Answering a previous question here on SO, I implemented a loop much more quickly than I could the stream equivalent, and the eventual stream version had subtle traps for the unwary.  I honestly think streams are overrated.)